# MultiSelect dropdown widget not showing selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, html-select

So I am using the multiselect widget from here: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/ and it is working fine in this instance. When I use strictly the same dropdown styling (to appear consistent) with a normal (only choose 1 option) dropdown my problem is that the drop down says 1 Selected. I need to change this to show the selected option, so 'Red' from Red, Yellow, Blue. The code that determines the selected option text is as follows:

```
  $.widget("ech.multiselect", {

    // default options
    options: {
      header: true,
      height: 175,
      minWidth: 225,
      classes: '',
      checkAllText: 'Check all',
      uncheckAllText: 'Uncheck all',
      noneSelectedText: 'Select options',
      selectedText: '# selected',
      selectedList: 0,
      show: null,
      hide: null,
      autoOpen: false,
      multiple: true,
      position: {},
      appendTo: "body"
    }
```

So, I need the selectedText to show the selected option if the dropdown has the class .normal. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code above doesn't sets the value. You need to override update function.

Comment: I understand that. How can I change it to dynamically pick up option text, rather that hardcoding it?

Comment: $(".stylized").multiselect({
    //selectedText:false
    header:false,
    multiple: false,
    minWidth: 80,
    selectedText: 'Select...',
     });

Comment: You can do that but What if there are more than one item selected, how do you want to display them ?

Comment: If more than one are selected, it is okay to remain as # selected. I'm just concerned about the dropdowns with a choose one option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change some code in the *jquery.multiselect.js* file. 
Replace the update function with this code:

```
// updates the button text. call refresh() to rebuild
    update: function() {
      var o = this.options;
      var $inputs = this.inputs;
      var $checked = $inputs.filter(':checked');
      var numChecked = $checked.length;
      var value;

      if(numChecked === 0) {
        value = o.noneSelectedText;
      } else if( numChecked===1){
    value = $checked.val();
} else {
        if($.isFunction(o.selectedText)) {
          value = o.selectedText.call(this, numChecked, $inputs.length, $checked.get());
        } else if(/\d/.test(o.selectedList) && o.selectedList > 0 && numChecked <= o.selectedList) {
          value = $checked.map(function() { return $(this).next().html(); }).get().join(', ');
        } else {
          value = o.selectedText.replace('#', numChecked).replace('#', $inputs.length);
        }
      }

      this._setButtonValue(value);

      return value;
    },
```

I haven't tested this but tell if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and im using javascript 1.7.2

The problem is the selectedText only taken into account for the first time loading and when i change the checkbox, slectedText of my button is not changing. Finally, i manage to fix the problem by modifying the jquery.multiselect.js like this :

In _create: function ()

Edit buttonlabel to:

buttonlabel = (this.buttonlabel = $(''))
                .html(o.noneSelectedText)
                .appendTo(button)
                .attr("id", "buttonlabel_" + this.element.attr('id')),

In update: function ()

Change this.buttonlabel.html( value ) to  $("#buttonlabel_" + this.element.attr("id")).text(value);

Hope this helps.

Cheers